# How can I fetch data in my content script? (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to fetch a simple .json file from my we accessible ressources into my content script. Here is what I tried so far:

manifest.json

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "MyExtension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "icons":{
            "128": "images/logo128x128.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [{
      "resources": ["data/data.json"],
      "matches": ["https://web-accessible-resources-1.glitch.me/*"]
    }]
}
```

content.js

```js
const jsondict_url = chrome.runtime.getURL("data.json")
console.log(jsondict_url)

var jsondict = fetch(jsondict_url)

console.log(jsondict)
```

This is the error message I get:

```js
chrome-extension://hbjmkaohgphjcegliejkcehbmjeggnnb/data.json
physique-generale-mecanique-PHYS-101-A#:1 
        
       Denying load of chrome-extension://hbjmkaohgphjcegliejkcehbmjeggnnb/data.json. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
       
content.js:6 Promise {<pending>}[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at chrome-extension://hbjmkaohgphjcegliejkcehbmjeggnnb/content.js:4:16
content.js:4 
        
       GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ content.js:4
content.js:4 
        
      Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at content.js:4:16
(anonymous) @ content.js:4
```

Edit: my files are organized this way

images/
logo128x128.png

data/data.json

content.js

manifest.js

Comment: Sounds like you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page.

Comment: I tried reloading and reuploading but both resulted in that same error

Comment: Your path is wrong. In manifest it's `data/data.json`.

Comment: The file data.json is indeed in the data folder . Neither changing the path in 'content.js' to 'data/data.js' nor moving the 'data.json' file up and changing the path in 'manifest.js' to 'data.json' and reloading solved the issue.

Comment: The only other explanation is that the web site URL in `matches` is wrong. For example the site is using an iframe with a different URL like jsfiddle does.

Answer (score 2):

Correcting the path in 'content.js' to 'data/data.js' helped.

I found one solution to my issue, I think I was misusing the function fetch. This introduction https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch to it uses the following code:

```js
fetch('./api/some.json') // 'data/data.json' in my case
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

My extension works fine with this.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying
`getURL("data.json")`
but your manifest states `"resources": ["data/data.json"]` so the path is incorrect in atleast one place? It should be `getURL("data/data.json")`.

You can also try adding `content.js` to `"web_accessible_resources"`.